# Compact simply-connected homogeneous symplectic manifold

Tags: symplectic-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

I was reading a paper in which the authors use the fact that any compact simply-connected homogeneous symplectic manifold have non-zero Euler characteristic. They prove it by quoting a theorem by Konstant, that implies that the manifold is symplectomorphic to a coadjoint orbit of a semisimple group, and then saying that compact coadjoint orbits of semisimple groups have non-zero Euler characteristic.

I was looking for a more direct proof of that fact. Do you know some?

Comment: can you please refer the paper you are reading?

Comment: Sure! The paper is "Homogeneous symplectic manifolds with Ricci-type curvature", by M. Cahen, S. Gutt, J. Horowitz and J. Rawnsley.

Comment: I'd be surprised that there be any really more direct proof of this, as there are implicit assumptions in your statement which strongly lead someone to follow this specific argument. One needs some characterization of what it means to be a homogeneous symplectic manifold. If the action is merely symplectic then your statement is wrong e.g. the 2-torus. So the action is Hamiltonian, but the Kirillov-Kostant-Souriau theorem rather easily yield that the space covers (& frequently is) a co-adjoint orbit. Some understanding of coadjoints orbits seem unavoidable, especially if $G$ is constrained...

Comment: The action is, a priori, just symplectic, Jordan. The torus is not simply-connected.

Comment: You're right, I had discarded the compactness and the simply-connectedness assumptions since if instead the group were compact and the action were Hamiltonian, then the manifold would be compact, simply-connected and symplectomorphic to a coadjoint orbit. The theorem of Kostant you're refering to is a sort of converse to this: any symplectic action on a simply-connected mfld is weakly Hamiltonian, and there's a canonical choice of a moment map for it when the mfld is compact. So the action is implicitly Hamiltonian, the mfld is a coadjoint orbit and the main purpose of my comment remains...